# How to change maven repository url on gradle

Tags: maven, build.gradle, nexus3, maven-repository

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/"
            allowInsecureProtocol true
            credentials {
                username project.repoUser
                password project.repoPassword
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.aca.lil'
            artifactId = 'arrrlib'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

I published this code by Nexus.

If I use this library, I should write this code.

```
maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
```

I wanna change this url to https.
Like `https://repo.aca.com/repository/maven-public/`

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/"
            allowInsecureProtocol true
            credentials {
                username project.repoUser
                password project.repoPassword
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.aca.lil'
            artifactId = 'acalil'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

I published this code on Nexus Repository.
If i use this library, I should write this code.

```
maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
```

I wanna change this url to https.
Like `https://repo.aca.com/repository/maven-public/`

How can I change this url? I wanna know right way to change it. Also is it good build.gradle code?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing....

Anyways, firstly if you are waiting to publish things to your local Nexus repository, you should use the publishToMavenLocal task, see the [reference doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

Secondly, you should be able to set whatever url for your repositories like explained [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html).